# What Type of Application Should I Choose?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'm creating an iPhone App which will have multiple views. Essentially, my homescreen will have two buttons, one of which will take you to a database of workout exercises which you can use to create your own workout and the other of which will take you to your saved workouts. I will be utilizing persistent data so that workout information can be saved.

What I am wondering is should this be a View Based Project, Navigation Based, Tab Based or something else? Let me know.

Comment: As always, it doesn't really matter which Xcode template you start from. Any template can be created from any other template, and after a little bit it won't matter which one you started from.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two distinct views, I would go for a UITabBarController (Tab Based)! So that way, you would have two tabs, the first one would be "Exercices" and the second one "Saved workouts", simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct a, dare I say, storyboard, for your entire app, to work out how the whole app will be navigated and organised in a way that is clear and intuitive the user.

From what you have said, there are two main sections to your app, so a top level tab-based UI seems a likely starting point, but you would need to think through the navigation thereafter to explore whether this makes sense.

Also think about whether you might want to port to the iPad in future, as that often has a Split View Controller at the top level, and you can't mix UITabBarViewContoller with UISplitViewController (officially) as they both have to be at the root level.